# Can I give other players powertools?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

Can I give other players the use of powertools via the Essentials plugin for Bukkit? Not the command (`/powertool`), but the ability to use an item as a powertool.

**Ex:** I assign the use of `/spawn` to a compass for PlayerA. However, he can not assign powertools to himself, he is only able to use the powertools assigned to him by other players.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? I do not understand the question.

Comment: @fireDude67 This edit should make it clearer.

Comment: Aren't the use of `/powertool` and the ability to make a powertool the same thing? I am confused.

Comment: @fredley No, I'm saying I want to give a player the ability to use a command that was assigned to an item via `/powertool` But however I don't want him to be ale to set powertools whenever he wants, I just want him to be able to use it at the moment I gave it to him, until I disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to give them the `essentials.powertool` permission, as documented on the [Command Reference Page](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/Command_Reference).